# android activitygroup with tabhost, keyboard not showing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tabhost, activitygroup

I have a tabhost and for each tab i have a activitygroup.

When the app starts and i press on a editText the keyboard comes out.
When i start a child activity and then go back to the main activity the keyboard doesnt come out anymore.

My code for starting the the subactivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowAddFoodToSelection.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

View view = ActivityGroupMeal.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(DataParser.activityIDMeal, i).getDecorView();

ActivityGroupMeal.group.setContentView(view);
```

my code to go back to the main activity

```
ActivityGroupMeal.group.back();
```

And the back code in the activitygroup:

```
public void back() {
        try {
            // if we set history.size() > 0 and we press back key on home
            // activity
            // and then on another activity we wont get back!
            if (history.size() > 1) {
                history.remove(history.size() - 1);
                // call the super.setContent view! so set the real view
                super.setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (history.size() >= 0)
                super.setContentView(history.get(0));
        }
    }
```

i set a `onClickListener` on the `editText` with the folowing code:

```
private void keyboardShow() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ActivityGroupMeal.group.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        boolean test = inputManager.showSoftInput(editTextSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        Toast.makeText(this, "show keyboard " + test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The first time it returns true and the time i come back from a childactivity it returns false.

When i click on a other tab and then back on the first tab, and then i click on the editText it returns true again.

Edit: i got a temporary fix, i set a `onClicklistener` on the editTextbox and then there i show the keyboard with code

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ActivityGroupMeal.group
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // show keyboard , when it fails first switch tab and then try again
        if (!inputManager.showSoftInput(null, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)) {
            // switch from tab and back
            // the keyboard wont show if we dont do this
            ShowHomeTab parentActivity;
            parentActivity = (ShowHomeTab) this.getParent().getParent();
            parentActivity.goToTab(DataParser.activityIDTracking);
            parentActivity.goToTab(DataParser.activityIDShowFoodList);

            inputManager.showSoftInput(null, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
```

When i come back from the childactivity i first have to switch tabs with code before the keyboard will show =/

anyone got a explanation for that ?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, did you happen to find a solution to this? Please do let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure. Try this [ActivityGroup](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) once.

Comment: @k9ty are u found any solution for this problem?????

Comment: @Hemant I had found a workaround, I shall try and dig up the code for you, I cannot promise that I can quickly find it as it has been a while since I worked on this.

Answer (score 4):

In my application where I used Activity Group, I used below code to resolve the same issue

```
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchName
                            .getApplicationWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and it was working fine. So try out this code snippet.

Comment: Tried this out. The keyboard displays on my device which has Android 4.0.4 firmware, but still does not display on devices with an older firmware version (2.3 and below)

Comment: Add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" to activity in manifest and check.

Comment: @PankajKumar facing same issue and use your code nothing happened??? is there any way to resolve the issue??

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding `requestFocus />` element to the definition of the `EditText`, i.e.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" >
        <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

If it doesn't help, request focus in your `back()` method by calling [`requestFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)